# Scheduled CSV Import's Deployement Error In Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, csv-import

I tried to update the employees record in an Netsuite system using the **Scheduled CSV Import**. 
while **deploying the Scheduled Script, I put the status has "Testing"** and **click "Save & Execute"** Button for testing purpose.

And then I checked the Execution Log in the Log it shows the following error message:

**" com.netledger.app.common.scripting.version1.nlobjCSVImportImplV1"**

**Scheduled Script Code:**

```
function scheduled(type) {

    var fileId = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_sfg_customer_rec_cus_param');
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','fileId:',fileId);
    var import1 = nlapiCreateCSVImport();
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','import1:',import1);
    var mapping = import1.setMapping('CUSTIMPORT_emp_rec_imp');
            //  Internal id for mapping
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','mapping:',mapping);
    var setPrimary = import1.setPrimaryFile(nlapiLoadFile(fileId));
            // id is Internal id for Employee file
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','setPrimary:',setPrimary);
    var submitImport = nlapiSubmitCSVImport(import1);
            // Importing is Done
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','submitImport:',submitImport);
}
```

Help me to find the solution for creating the scheduled CSV Import.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possible issues with your code:

1. When I have done this I've used all lower case for the import id. e.g. use 'customimport_emp_rec_imp' not 'CUSTIMPORT_emp_rec_imp'
2. Make sure the saved csv import definition is public
3. Set a job name with import1.setOption("jobName", "Employee Import");